# How to retrieve Session from wmc.io AemContext

Tags: java, unit-testing, aem

I'm working with *wcm.io*'s [AemContext](http://wcm.io/testing/aem-mock/usage.html) to Unit-Test my AEM classes.

*Is there any way to obtain a JCR Session from it?* Or may be a mailing list that might yield an answer?

I tried

```
import io.wcm.testing.mock.aem.junit.AemContext;
import javax.jcr.Session;
// ...

public class MyTest {

    @Rule
    public AemContext aemContext = new AemContext();

    @Test
    public void selfTest() throws Exception {
        // something like this is called inside the class I test.
        // I need the Session to *not* be null.
        Session session = aemContext.resourceResolver().adaptTo(Session.class);

        assertNotNull("session is " + session, session);
    }

    // actual tests follow that do not work due to the problem above
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you did not specified ResorceResolver type, it used `DEFAULT_RESOURCERESOLVER_TYPE`, which is `ResourceResolverType.RESOURCERESOLVER_MOCK` (please check [API](http://wcm.io/testing/aem-mock/apidocs/io/wcm/testing/mock/aem/junit/AemContext.html)), with no underlying JCR repository.

Please check available types and select one which will suite you [there](http://wcm.io/testing/aem-mock/apidocs/org/apache/sling/testing/mock/sling/ResourceResolverType.html).
In most cases you can use `JCR_MOCK`. Please refer to docs to get more info.